# c# Random numbers put in an array

Tags: c#

is it possible to store the random numbers you get from this code.
Into an array?
sorry im a potato in c#.

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random randomNum = new Random();
    int random1 = randomNum.Next(1, 99);
    label10.Text = Convert.ToString(random1);
}
```

Comment: Why not? declare an `int[]` (int array) and store the variable in one of its indexes. Have you tried?

Comment: Sure it is possible. For example create an array and generate random value for each entry in the array.

Comment: Ofcourse it's possible, but you can also use a list.

Comment: _sorry im a potato_ o.O

Comment: In order to leave your vegetable state behind you must make an effort of your own. Asking here doesn't count ;-).

Answer (score 2):

Of course there is the "obligatory" LINQ solution:

```
var size = 10;
var random = new Random();
var array = Enumerable.Range(0, size).Select(_ => random.Next(1, 99)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes declare an array in you class and save the variable in it it's very easy:

```
class TestClass
{
    private string[] labels;


    public TestClass(int sizeOfArray size)
    {
        labels = new string[size];
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random randomNum = new Random();
        int random1 = randomNum.Next(1, 99);
        String labelText = Convert.ToString(random1);
        label10.Text = labelText;
        labels[determineFreeIndex] = labelText;
    }



}
```

Comment: The name "label10" makes me want to store the labels in an array as well, or perhaps use a tuple or create a custom class, or perhaps store *only* the labels (and use their text property to store the number as text).